# Extract the names of files from HDFS using Python

Tags: python, pyspark, subprocess, hdfs, filenames

I am using Python and I need to get the list of the file names I have in a folder  (saved as HDFS) directly through python and separate the name of the files (which are .wav files) from their path (I just need the name). I was thinking may be I can use pyspark or subprocess but they only give the whole 'path+filename' as bytes, not separated and it is pretty hard to separate them.
I would be thankful if someone can help me with this.

```
import subprocess 

p = subprocess.Popen("hdfs dfs -ls <directory>",
shell=True,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for line in p.stdout.readlines():
print(line)
```

Comment: Hey! Please show us some code you wrote :)

Comment: @KasiaGogolek done

Comment: it is more convenient to use HDFS CLI library available in python. it has has a function similar to os.walk where you can get all file names.

Answer (score 0):

this gives output in list data Type

```
import subprocess
out=subprocess.check_output(["hadoop","fs","-ls","<directory>"] ).split("\n")
out
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [HDFS CLI](http://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which walks through hdfs recursively,

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient
client = InsecureClient(hostname, user)

get_file = []
for dir_,sub_dir, files in client.walk():
    if files:
        get_file.append(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
hdfs_path = '/path/to/the/designated/folder'
process = Popen(f'hdfs dfs -ls -h {hdfs_path}', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
std_out, std_err = process.communicate()
list_of_file_names = [fn.split(' ')[-1].split('/')[-1] for fn in std_out.decode().readlines()[1:]][:-1]
list_of_file_names_with_full_address = [fn.split(' ')[-1] for fn in std_out.decode().readlines()[1:]][:-1]
```